# Model defines __str__, how can I access the primary_key value?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm doing a web app using django and jinja2.In my models.py my class defines the `__str__` function, to return a friendly text when referring to the objects of that class.

```
class MySystem (models.Model):
    system_id         = models.AutoField(primary_key=True),
    system_name       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_system     = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} > {}".format(self.parent_system, self.system_name)

class Detail (models.Model):
    detail_id         = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    system_id         = models.ForeignKey(MySystem, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title             = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} > {}".format(self.system_id, self.title)
```

I have a Detail object, and I want the ID of its system. When I try to access the primary key, it returns the string instead of the ID.

```
<td> <a href="/base/system/{{detail.system_id}}" > {{ detail.system_id.system_name }} </a> </td>
```

I tried `detail.system_id.system_id` and it returns `django.db.models.fields.AutoField`. I want it to return the numeric ID for the link.

Comment: Be careful when following foreign keys in your `__str__`. If you read attributes of the linked object it can result in one additional SQL query per object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my solution. What I need to do is `detail.system_id.id`.

Comment: I got my solution but I have no idea how I was supposed to figure this out. If anyone know where I can find this in the documentation to help me find answers on my own, I'll appreciate.